# Order by derived column in a windowed query

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by

I have a windowed query like below:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY NULL) AS TotalRows,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER
        (
            ORDER BY MyDerivedColumn asc
        ) AS RowNumber
        ,MyDerivedColumn = (SELECT TOP 1 SomeColumn FROM SomeTable ORDER BY SomeOtherColumn DESC)
            ...
```

and I can not get it to order by derived columns (as shown above).  I've been able to order by derived columns using "regular" queries by using the column index in the order by clause IE:

```
ORDER BY 2
```

but I get an error when trying to perform my windowed query that says:

> Windowed functions do not support integer indices as ORDER BY clause expressions.

how can I order by derived columns like the above?

TIA

EDIT:  Posting my actual code per request.

```
    SET @SQL = '
SELECT *
FROM
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY NULL) AS TotalRows,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER
        (
            ORDER BY StudentDissertationStageDescription ASC
        ) AS RowNumber,
        sc.FirstName
        ,sc.LastName
        ,sc.StudentId
        ,spos.ProgramOfStudy AS ProgramOfStudy
        ,(
            SELECT TOP 1 [StudentDissertationStageDescription]
            FROM
                [StudentDissertationStage] AS sd
            WHERE sc.StudentId = sd.StudentId
            ORDER BY sd.[StudentDissertationStage] DESC
        ) AS StudentDissertationStageDescription 
    FROM 
        StudentClasses AS sc
    LEFT JOIN
        StudentProgramOfStudy AS spos
    ON
        spos.StudentId = sc.StudentId
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[FacultyAssignments] fa 
         ON sc.StudentId = fa.StudentID
    WHERE 1 = 1
    '
    IF @filter IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = @SQL + @filter
    END
    SET @SQL = @SQL + '
    GROUP BY
        sc.FirstName
        ,sc.LastName
        ,sc.SyStudentID
        ,spos.ProgramOfStudy
    ) AS TheTableSet
    WHERE
        RowNumber BETWEEN ' + 
        CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @startrow) + 
        ' AND ' + 
        CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @endrow) + ''
    EXEC(@SQL)
```

Comment: All expressions within a single `SELECT` clause are computed "as if" they're all being evaluated in parallel - this means there can't be any dependencies between them since the values aren't available when evaluation starts. You need to use a CTE or a subquery to introduce another `SELECT` clause that is (logically) evaluated earlier and then put the "depended upon" expressions into that clause. For complex dependency chains, you may need to introduce more CTEs/Subqueries to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
;with cte as (
    select
        1 as num,
        (SELECT TOP 1 SomeColumn FROM SomeTable ORDER BY SomeOtherColumn DESC) as MyDerivedColumn
)
SELECT
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY NULL) AS TotalRows,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MyDerivedColumn asc) AS RowNumber
FROM cte
```

You can also write that query with a subquery:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY NULL) AS TotalRows,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MyDerivedColumn asc) AS RowNumber
FROM (
    select
        1 as num,
        (SELECT TOP 1 SomeColumn FROM SomeTable ORDER BY SomeOtherColumn DESC) as MyDerivedColumn
) t
```

This way, your code would look something like this:

```
SET @SQL = '
SELECT *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY NULL) AS TotalRows,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY StudentDissertationStageDescription ASC) AS RowNumber,
            sc.FirstName,
            sc.LastName
            sc.StudentId
            spos.ProgramOfStudy AS ProgramOfStudy
        FROM (
            sc.FirstName,
            sc.LastName,
            sc.StudentId,
            spos.ProgramOfStudy AS ProgramOfStudy,
            (
                SELECT TOP 1 [StudentDissertationStageDescription]
                FROM [StudentDissertationStage] AS sd
                WHERE sc.StudentId = sd.StudentId
                ORDER BY sd.[StudentDissertationStage] DESC
            ) AS StudentDissertationStageDescription,
            DissertationChair = staff.[FirstName] + '' '' + staff.[LastName],
            DissertationEmail = staff.[email]
            FROM StudentClasses AS sc
            LEFT JOIN StudentProgramOfStudy AS spos ON spos.StudentId = sc.StudentId
            LEFT JOIN [dbo].[FacultyAssignments] fa ON sc.StudentId = fa.StudentID
            WHERE 1 = 1
            '
            IF @filter IS NOT NULL
            BEGIN
                SET @SQL = @SQL + @filter
            END
            SET @SQL = @SQL + '
        ) t
        GROUP BY
            t.FirstName,
            t.LastName,
            t.SyStudentID,
            t.ProgramOfStudy
    ) AS TheTableSet

    WHERE
        RowNumber BETWEEN ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @startrow) + ' AND ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @endrow)

EXEC(@SQL)
```

Comment: I tried the subquery route and I get this error: "Invalid column name 'MyDerivedCol'."

Comment: Could you post or add a comment with your entire code for the query?

Comment: added "real" code to my OP.  The real error I get is this: "Invalid column name 'StudentDissertationStageD'."

Comment: I can order by any of the other columns, it's only the derived (StudentDissertationStageDescription) column that fails.

Comment: The problem is the you are trying to order by the derived column in the same query where you label it in the select statement. In the logical order of execution, the group by occurs before the select, that's why SQL Server returns an error for your query. I'm adding another answer posting your updated code with some adjustments. The code might have some mistakes, since I'm not really able to test it, but I believe it will get you in the right direction. Hope this helps.

Comment: The bottom line is that you need to use a subquery to define [StudentDissertationStageDescription] so you can use it in OUTER queries.